# When is an ambiguous grammar or production rule OK? (bison shift/reduce warnings)

Tags: parsing, bison, shift-reduce-conflict

There are certainly plenty of docs and howtos on resolving shift/reduce errors.  The bison docs suggest the correct solution is usually to just %expect them and deal with it.

When you have things like this:

```
S: S 'b' S | 't'
```

You can easily resolve them like this:

```
S: S 'b' T | T
T: 't'
```

My question is:  Is it better to leave the grammar a touch ambiguous and %expect shift/reduce problems or is it better to try to adjust the grammar to avoid them?  I suspect there is a balance and it's based on the needs of the author, but I don't really know.

Comment: yup.  Not sure it changes the problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read it, Your question is "When is an ambiguous grammar or production rule OK?"

First consider the language you are describing.  What would be the implication of allowing an ambiguous production rule into the language.

Your example describes a language which might include an expression like: `t b t b t b t`

The expression, resolved as in your second example would be `(((( t ) b t) b t ) b t )` but in an ambiguous grammer it could also become `( t b ( t b ( t b ( t))))` or even `( t b t ) b ( t b t )`.  Which could be valid might depend on the language.  If the `b` operator models subtraction, it really shouldn't be ambiguous, but if it was addition, it might be ok.  This really depends on the language.

The second question to consider is what the resulting grammar source file ends up looking like, after the conflicts are resolved.  As with other source code, a grammar is meant to be read by humans, and secondarily also by computers.  Prefer a notation that gives a clearer explanation of what the parser is trying to do from the grammar.  That is, if the parser is executing some possibly undefined behavior, for example, order of evaluation of a function's arguments in an eager language, make the grammar *look* ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

You can guide the conflict resolution with operator precedence. Declare `'b'` as an left- or right-associative operator and you have covered at least that case.

For more complex patterns, as long as the final parser produces the correct result in all cases, the warnings isn't much to worry about. Though if you can't get it to give the correct result using declarations you would have to rewrite the grammar.

Comment: Well, yeah, my example was intentionally trivial.  The other usual example is the if then else (aka dangling else).  That's harder to resolve without shift/reduce -- the question is: is it worth it.

Answer (score 1):

In my compiler course last semester we used bison, and built a compiler for a subset of pascal.

If the language is complex enough, you will have some errors. As long as you understand why they are there, and what you'd have to do to remove them, we found it to be alright. If something was there, but due to the behaviour would work as we wanted it to, and would require much to much thought and work to make it worth while (and also complicating the grammar), we left it alone. Just make sure you fully understand the error, and document it somewhere (even for yourself), so that you always know what's going on with it.

It's a cost/benefit analysis once things get really involved, but IMHO, fixing it should be considered FIRST, then actually figure out what the work would be (and if that work breaks something else, or makes something else harder), and go from there. Never pass them off as commonplace.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to prove that a grammar is unambiguous, I tend to write it first as a [Parsing Expression Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar), and then convert it by hand to whatever grammar type the tool set I'm using for the project needs.  In my experience, the need for this level of proof is very rare, though, since most shift/reduce conflicts I have come across have been fairly trivial ones to show the correctness of (on the order of your example).